# How to check if Dictionary is initialized in swift 3

Tags: dictionary, swift3

Given a struct with one property - an empty Dictionary of type `<String, Any>`:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar:Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
}
```

and struct extension with custom initalizer:

```
extension Foo {
    init(json: [String: Any]) {
        if let bar = json["bar"] {
            self.bar = bar as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to check further down in my code (after instantiating that Struct) if `bar` property on my `Foo` struct does not have a default `[:]` value:

```
let param:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["bar": 12]
let options = Foo(param)

if (options.bar != [:]) {
    // ok, the bar is set - do something
}
```

the `param` dictionary is a user-supplied JSON object which must have a type `<String, Any>` as it can contain eiter String:Int or String:String values.

Unfortunately the above `if` statement gives me:

```
Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Dictionary<String, Any>' and '[AnyHashable : Any]'
```

Comment: Use isEmpty method  `if (options.bar.isEmpty) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isEmpty` method

You are intializing wrong here

```
 if let bar = json["bar"] {
        self.bar = bar as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    }
```

`json["bar"]` returns int and casting to `Dictionary` type,crashes.

Change your extension as

```
extension Foo {
    init(json: [String: Any]) {

        if let _ = json["bar"] {

            self.bar = json
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can check as

```
 let param:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["bar": 12]
 let options = Foo(json: param)

 if (options.bar.isEmpty) {
        print("empty")
  }else{
        print("not emtpy")
       }
```